# Can I set wordpress theme via code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been working on wordpress for a while. I know that we can manage themes via the admin panel and the selected theme and its configuration details are stored in the database.

Is there any way I can set the theme via my wordpress code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `switch_theme` function on the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme)

#### Description

> Switches current theme to new template and stylesheet names.
>   Accepts one argument: $stylesheet of the theme. ($stylesheet is the name of your folder slug. It's the same value that you'd use for a child theme, something like `twentythirteen`.) It also accepts an additional function signature of two arguments: $template then $stylesheet. This is for backwards compatibility.

#### Usage

> `<?php switch_theme( $stylesheet ) ?>`